# How to add finger bones to MakeHuman Rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, makehuman, motion-capture

I use a *MakeHuman* model to animate motion capture data. Now I would like to animate the finger movement, but the *MakeHuman* rig has no finger bones. I added the bones to the rig now, but I can't get them working right because when I set *automatic weight* the *MakeHuman* rig is working wrong.

Is there a way to add *automatic weight* only to the 'new' finger bones?